# If $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are iid, can I remove the subscript?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are iid. Since they are identically distributed, can I drop the subscript in the following expression?

$\textbf{E}\left[(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu))^{4}\right] = \textbf{E}\left[(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_-\mu))^{4}\right]$.

True or false? Why or why not?

Thank you :)

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ The purpose of this question is because I am attempting to directly prove the following equality:

$\textbf{E}\left[(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu))^{4}\right] = n\textbf{E}[(X_i-\mu)^4]+3n(n-1)\sigma^{4}.$

I've proven it by induction, where I assumed that I could drop the index on the right-hand side. Now I am trying to prove it directly and am curious if I can drop the index inside the summation on the left-hand side.

Comment: You could have dropped the subscript if you did not have product of $X_i$ in the expectation. For example if the exponent $4$ was for each $X_i-\mu$ and not the whole sum of differences.

Comment: Then why can't I drop the one on the right-hand side, since it does not involve the product of $X_i$'s? Referring to $\textbf{E}[(X_i-\mu)^4]$ here.

Comment: In your Edit you can drop it. I was referring to the first expression.

Comment: Note that r.h.s. of equality must looks like 
$n\textbf{E}[(X_i-\mu)^4]+3n(n-1)\sigma^{4}$.

Comment: Yes, very sorry about the typo. I forgot the 4th power there.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Independent identically distributed random variables are not identical: 
in general, $X_1+X_2\neq 2X_1$. Say, if you toss a coin: results of different tosses are i.i.d., and the equality $X_1=X_2$ holds with probability $\frac12$ only.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying @NCh. What about in the expression $\textbf{E}[X_i-\mu]$? I was told by someone I trust that this subscript can be dropped; I was unsure of the reasoning -- I see no reason why your explanation wouldn't also apply here.

Comment: @mXdX If you have $\mathbf E[X_i-\mu]$, it does not depend on $i$. And you want to avoid indices inside sum. It is not possible.

Comment: @NCh very sorry, I read the equation wrongly.

Comment: @NCh Sorry, are you saying that I can drop the index in the right-hand side? (see edit). Just clarifying.

Comment: @mXdX In the r.h.s. of what? It is true that $$\textbf{E}\left[(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\mu))^{4}\right] = n\textbf{E}[(X_i-\mu)^4]+3n(n-1)\sigma^{4}=n\textbf{E}[(X-\mu)^4]+3n(n-1)\sigma^{4}.$$

Comment: I just don't understand why you dropped that subscript, based on your explanation in your original post. Is there an easy way to understand the difference?

Comment: The original post answered the original question. The variables $X_i$ have the same distribution, therefore their expectaitions are the same. And the variables itself are not the same!

Answer (score 1):

If we were to expand out $(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu))^4$, we'd find terms like $X_1X_2X_3X_4$ in it. Removing the subscripts turns this into $X^4$.

But $\mathbb E[X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4] \ne \mathbb E[X^4]$. The first one of these, by independence, simplifies to $\mathbb E[X_1] \mathbb E[X_2] \mathbb E[X_3] \mathbb E[X_4]$, or $\mathbb E[X]^4$. We can't do the same thing to $\mathbb E[X^4]$ because it is not a product of four independent random variables: $X$ is not independent from itself.

Comment: This made a lot of sense to me; could you explain to me now why $\textbf{E}[(X_i-\mu)^4]=\textbf{E}[(X-\mu)^4]$? Is it because we only find terms that are products of the single $X_i$, which has the same expected value for all $i$?

Comment: It doesn't have just the same expected value, it has the same distribution. The value $\mathbb E[(X_i - \mu)^4]$ depends only on the distribution of $X_i$, and because $X_i$ has the same distribution as $X$, the value $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)^4]$ must be equal to it.